# Proving Proposition 10.10 of Kanamori's The Higher Infinite using partial orders

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Proposition 10.10 of Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite* states:

> Suppose that $R$ is a [poset], $G$ is $R$-generic over $V$, and $N$ is a transitive $\in$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ such that $V \subseteq N \subseteq V[G]$. Then there is a [poset] $P$ and a $P$-name $\dot{Q}$ such that $\Vdash_P \dot{Q}$ is a [poset] with $P * \dot{Q}$ isomorphic to $R$ so that, thus identifying $R$ with $P * \dot{Q}$ is as in 10.9(b), $V[G_0] = N$.

Proposition 10.9(b) of the same book states:

> Conversely, suppose that $G$ is $P * \dot{Q}$-generic, and set:
> $$
> G_0 = \{p \in P \mid \exists \dot{q}(\langle p,\dot{q} \rangle \in G)\}, \text{and} \\
> G_1 = \{q^{G_0} \mid \exists p(\langle p,\dot{q} \rangle \in G)\}
> $$
> Then $G_0$ is $P$-generic, $G_1$ is $\dot{Q}^{G_0}$-generic over $V[G_0]$, and $G = G_0 * G_1$.

Kanamori referred to Jech's *Set Theory* (2003) for the proof of Proposition 10.10, which uses a completely Boolean algebraic approach. I would like to ask for a proof of Proposition 10.10 without using any tools involving Boolean algebra (a quick search in other common set theory texts does not give any such proof).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. Someone asked this already. But I think there was no particular answer.

Comment: The thing with partial orders is that they can have all sort of bad properties to them, which will disappear when moving to the Boolean completion. So in some sense, Boolean completions provide us with a semblance of canonicity. Which is important when proving such theorems.